# Can we use location services as mandatory in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, apple-push-notifications, location-services

Actually My app rejected under below 2 content where as apple approved the thrice before this build for same feature.

> From Apple
>   5.3 - Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent, as well as apps that require Push Notifications to function, will be rejected
>   **(Here I haven't made APNS notification mandatory)**

5.3 Details

> We noticed that your app requires Push Notifications in order to function. Specifically, your app requires users to enable Location Services at login.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Push Notifications must be optional and must obtain the user's consent to be used within the app

So my question is  can we not make location services mandatory in iOS .Actually I need a location details in login.Apple while testing turned of the location services where I have kept the alert message as **"@"Turn on Location Service for this app in settings""**.they said rejecting due to this alert message

I have used

```
if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
          [self ShowLocationAlert:@"Turn on Location Service for this app in settings"];
    }e
```

Comment: You cannot force user to turn on his location services, its strictly restricted by apple.

Comment: Can you please provide me any information link on this if you know on the restriction ..

Comment: I need some information, If user will not turn on location services and if he tries to login into your app, whether you are allowing him to login into the app or not.

Comment: No, I am not allowing user without location details..But my query is , this feature we are using in app since 1.5 years (already in App Store currently) ,and apple has approved this many times when we uploaded..Not getting how come apple rejected on this feature now

Comment: @Sujania, If your functionality is depending upon the location services then and then only you can use such things, i.e Tinder application requires location services in order to use the application. And Push notifications should not be compulsory.

Comment: It happens for many people, app review solely depends upon the reviewer.Some may accept the app and some may reject the app. After all its their store. If you have any complaints you can contact App Review Baord and submit an appeal.

Comment: @Madhu Yes I have already appealed regarding this  but  waiting for reply

Comment: @Sujania have you allowed the user's to login without enabling the location service? I am on the same condition which you faced location service is mandatory in my app too and now the rejected my app on basis of this. Can you share the your findings on this.